# mongodb ignoring sparse on array index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

With mongo 4.4.3 I am creating a unique and sparse index into an array:

```
db.test.createIndex( { "array": 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true } )
```

I fill it with some test data:

```
db.test.insert({})
db.test.insert({array:[]})
db.test.insert({array:[ "a" ]})
db.test.insert({array:[ "b" ]})
db.test.insert({array:[ "c", "d" ]})
```

Now I would expect the following:

```
db.test.insert({array:[ "a" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "b" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "c" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "d" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({})              #SUCCESS
db.test.insert({array:[]})      #SUCCESS
```

Instead I am getting:

```
db.test.insert({array:[ "a" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "b" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "c" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({array:[ "d" ]}) #FAIL
db.test.insert({})              #SUCCESS
db.test.insert({array:[]})      #FAIL
```

With the problem being:

```
"E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.test index: array_1 dup key: { array: undefined }"
```

An empty array seems to be treated as `undefined` - but why is sparse ignored for that?

Is there a way to get the behavior that I expected (without an impact on performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/

> Partial indexes only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression. By indexing a subset of the documents in a collection, partial indexes have lower storage requirements and reduced performance costs for index creation and maintenance.

**Option 1**

```
db.test.createIndex(
    { "array": 1 },
    { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "array": { $gt: [] } } }
)
```

Create index only if array is gt `[]` by using `partialFilterExpression: { "array": { $gt: [] } }`

---

**Option 2**

```
db.test.createIndex(
    { "array": 1 },
    { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "array.0": { $exists: true } } }
)
```

`"array.0": { $exists: true }` will check if array index 0 is available that is array has some value.

Comment: Thanks! Are you aware of any performance differences when using partial indexes like that?

Comment: @tcurdt for making the array unique it's perfect, but you can't leverage this with your query and sorts. For details read - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#query-coverage

Answer (score 0):

@tcurdt When you make a query to the array, make sure to add the same partial filter expression to the query, i.e.

```js
{array: "my_array_value", "array.0": {$exists: true}}
```

Otherwise, Mongo will not use the index.